# Restricting Anonymous user to see only public content from SharePoint 2013 index

Tags: 2013, authentication, enterprise-search

I have crawled and indexed some public and private(that requires windows authentication) websites using SharePoint 2013 Search.

I also added new web app and created new site collection using built-en template (Enterprise Search Center). Also provided Anonymous access to the search site.

Now Anyone can access search site and make searches on it. When some Anonymous user make some search, it shows results from public as well as private sites.

How can I restrict Anonymous user to see only public indexed items in search results not private?

Comment: Have you read this question? Might be what you're looking for... http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/18874/sharepoint-anonymous-user-search-results

Comment: @ThomasVochten, Yes this question is similar to my  problem but the solution specified in that thread is not working. Thanks for this reference.